# Is there a Visual Studio or Resharper keystroke to copy-to-clipboard the current line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I see a keystroke to cut the current line, but nothing to copy.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If no one is aware of anything I'll email JetBrains and post their response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Visual Studio option, not ReSharper. If you enable the "Apply cut or copy commands to blank lines when there is no selection" option in *Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages*, copying without a selection (eg. just `Ctrl+C`) will copy the entire line.

[image]

This is the same option that enables cutting the entire line as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed!  Didn't even realize I could do it.

Answer (score 4):

Just put the caret at the beginning of the line and press CTRL + C. This will copy the line. Doing the same with CTRL + X will cut it.

Comment: I was hoping to do it without moving my cursor.

Comment: How would you move to the line you want to copy without placing the caret at the line you want? (Either via the mouse or the keyboard)

Comment: LOL, I'm explaining this horribly.  I'm sitting on a line of code (cursor is already there, perhaps in the middle of the line) and I realize I want to get this line copied.  I meant that I was hoping I could now just hit something to put it on the clipboard without, like I used to do, home -> shift-end -> ctrl-c

Comment: lol oh, sorry I get it now :D. Quickest way would probably be `Home` then CTRL + C. If you have the option enabled in adrianbanks' picture, it should copy.

Comment: No problem, mate.  Thanks for your time.  Cheers!  Oh, and as one of the other answer mentions it turns it that as long as I have no selection, I can just hit ctrl-c regardless of where I'm at on the line.  I had no idea!

Comment: No probs. Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're anywhere in a line, with nothing selected, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will copy the entire line.

You can immediately hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it, and it'll appear beneath the line you're at.

Similarly, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> will cut the line and put it in the clipboard.

And last, and probably least, hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, will delete the entire line (but still put it in your clipboard).